# Checking blackberry network type

Tags: network-programming, blackberry, 3g, cellular-network

I'm trying to check the cellular network type of a blackberry. What I would like to retrieve is the type that is displayed in the top right of my screen.

So,2G, 3G, Edge or SOS (in emergencies). Currently the closest I have got is using the function getNetworkType, which always returns GPRS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use getNetworkService()

for example

```
int service = RadioInfo.getNetworkService();


if ( (service & RadioInfo.NETWORK_SERVICE_DATA ) != 0 ){
   // GPRS
}
if ( (service & RadioInfo.NETWORK_SERVICE_UMTS ) != 0 ){
   // 3G
}
if ( (service & RadioInfo.NETWORK_SERVICE_EDGE ) != 0 ){
   // EDGE
}
```

There are still other status, such as EVD0 for CDMA network
Please check on **RadioInfo.NETWORK_SERVICE_***